# In Java, call set.iterator(), what is the internal process for this method?

Tags: java, iterator, set

I just noticed that the time complexity of Method Set.iterator() is constant.

If so, it means that when java generates a set and adds elements into it, the element has been connected with cursor. Otherwise, when calling Set.iterator(), it has to iterate all elements in this set, which cost linear time complexity.

So I want to know how a set saves elements in Java, and when calling Set.iterator(), how does a set return an iterator?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "saves elements".  When you're iterating over a set, at no point are you adding elements back into it.

Comment: Depends on the Set implementation. The jdk implementations are [open source](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/), so you could take a look there -- and if you have specific questions about something you find, then those would be on topic here. This question as stated is too broad.

Comment: Usually the `Set.iterator()` method will return you a wrapper object over the values in the set. It will only start iterating over the values when you call its `next` method.

Comment: @yshavit I think everyone knows Java is open source but there are still tons of questions in stackoverflow. That is because not anyone could understand or has time to learn how every piece of source code is implemented. I think my question is specific enough.

Comment: @HanLi With respect, I think the fact that you got a fairly vague answer ("in some cases, it delegates down to a Map's iterator, and the implementation for that differs depending on the Map type") speaks to the fact that this question is too broad. Unless that's the level of specificity you were looking for -- in which case you should probably accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are different types of sets in Java.  The primary two available are HashSet and TreeSet.  Both use maps for their implementation, HashMap and TreeMap.  So when you add an item, it checks if that item is there already by doing a map lookup, which is close to constant time for HashMap, and for TreeMap is log time.

Adding to the set is not constant time, it depends on the backing map, but generally HashMap is near constant time and TreeMap is log time.

To return an iterator, the set uses the map's key iterator. The backing map uses the set elements as keys.  Iterating the keys of a hashmap is rather straightforward, you just go through the array and the bins at each element.  Iterating through a binary tree can be done using various known traversal algorithms.